# Android Operating System Overrides in app font

Tags: java, android, fonts, overriding

I am developing an android app, i have added some font for my app, but after installing the app if i change my android operating system fonts, it also changes my in app font. Is there any way to prevent my application from operating system to overrides the font?

Answer (score 1):

In your `res` folder, right click and select **New** -> **Android Resource Directory**. A new window pops up, change the resource type to `font` and select OK.

Mostly, I add my custom font file always in `.ttf` to that font resource directory which you can download from [Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/).

After adding the font file to that directory, go to `res` -> `values` -> `styles.xml` directory.

Under style with name `AppTheme`, add a new item `android:fontFamily` and set the value to the font in the font resource directory. i.e.

`<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/NAME_OF_FONT_FILE</item>`

Note, `android:fontFamily` requires an API level of 16 :)

Comment: Well i know the procedure of changing font and i did it in same way. But the main problem is that if I change font of operating system in my phone then it also changes fonts inside my android app